# Lower Bounds For Floating Points

Tags: c, floating-point, standards, epsilon

Are there any lower bounds for floating point types in C? Like there are lower bounds for integral types (int being at least 16 bits)?

Comment: Hi Geekhero, welcome to StackOverflow.  If you wish to reply in the comments, at the bottom of your own question there is a grey text link which reads "add comment."  This is how people communicate with each other here.

Comment: do you want to map floats to fewer bits (less accuracy) ?

Comment: You cannot comment with only 1 reputation point.

Comment: @ndim: Yes you can. "you can always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you've asked, even with 1 rep." (faq)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  `float.h` contains constants such as:

`FLT_EPSILON, DBL_EPSILON, LDBL_EPSILON` this is the least magnitude non-zero value which can be represented by `float`, `double`, and `long double` representations.

`FLT_MAX` and `FLT_MIN` represent the extreme positive and negative numbers which can be represented for `float`.  Similar `DBL_` and `LDBL_` are available.

`FLT_DIG, DBL_DIG, LDBL_DIG` are defined as the number of decimal digits  precision.

You are asking for either the `xxx_MIN` or the `xxx_EPSILON` value.

Along these lines, here is a question wherein [I posted some code which displays the internals of a 64-bit IEEE-754 floating-point number.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697425/how-to-print-out-each-bit-of-a-floating-point-number/1697734#1697734)

Comment: That wasn't the question. Geekhero is asking for the bounds which the language puts on those constants, not how to get the values in a particular implementation.

Comment: Surely you realize the bounds are not defined by the language standard, but by the implementation?  And that most implementations adhere to IEEE-754?  But the OP can't count on that because the answer will vary by platform?

Comment: The language standard defines bounds *on the bounds*. The OP says "like ... int being at least 16 bits". Similarly, float represents at least 6 decimal places. If it represents more, then FLT_DIG will be greater than 6, but it must not be less.

Comment: Steve, your point of view might be a better answer to the OP's question.  You should add an answer.

Comment: Unless you would like to community wiki this answer I wrote, I'd be glad to change it, but usually when I transform to wiki, nobody participates in the edits but me.

Comment: Roman, ndim, and Konamiman's answers are to the question that I think was intended: they all point to lists of the minimum values required for the constants you mention (although they each chose different references, so I suppose there's something to be said for one answer to rule them all...)

Answer (score 3):

To be strict and grounded:

[ISO/IEC 9899:TC2: (WG14/N1124m May 6, 2005)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf):

5.2.4.2.2, Characteristics of floating types <float.h>

Comment: Also, Annex F of that draft proposes that floats should adhere to IEEE-754, but is not specific about the size of long double.

Answer (score 2):

`float.h` contains many macros describing various properties of the floating types (including `FLT_MIN` and `DBL_MIN`).

The description of the requirements of the limits in`float.h` is given in the standard (C90 or C99 - 5.2.4.2.2 "Characteristics of floating types").

In particular, according to the standard any implementation must support a lower-bound of at least `1E-37` for `float` or `double`.  But an implementation is free to do better than that (and indicate what it does in `FLT_MIN` and `DBL_MIN`).

See this question for information on where to get a copy of the standards documents if you need one:

- [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-x-standard)

Comment: That wasn't the question. Geekhero is asking for the bounds which the language puts on those constants, not how to get the values in a particular implementation

Comment: The question can probably be reasonably interpreted either way. Regardless, a better answer would discuss both areas (they're still kind of the same answer - the documentation for `float.h` talks about the required limits for an implementation, the contents of a particular `float.h` describe  a particular implementation's limits.  I've updated the answer to try to better cover both angles.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps: [float.h reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cfloat/) (it is C++, I'm not sure if it applies to plain C as well)

Answer (score 1):

This [Draft C99 standard (PDF)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1336.pdf) notes minimum values for floating point type precision in section 5.2.4.2.2.

(Found via [Wikipedia on C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99).)

Answer (score 0):

A useful reference here is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~dws/grouplinks/floating_point_math.pdf).

The nature of a floating point number — its size, precision, limits — is really defined by the hardware, rather than the programming language. A single-precision float on an x86 is the same in C, C#, Java, and any other practical programming language. (The exception is esoteric programming languages that implement odd widths of floating point number in software.)

Answer (score 0):

Excerpts from the Standard draft (n1401.pdf)

```
                                      Annex F
                                    (normative)
                       IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic
    F.1 Introduction
1   ... An implementation that defines _ _STDC_IEC_559_ _ shall conform to
    the specifications in this annex. ...

    F.2 Types
1   The C floating types match the IEC 60559 formats as follows:
    -- The float type matches the IEC 60559 single format.
    -- The double type matches the IEC 60559 double format.
    -- The long double type matches an IEC 60559 extended format ...
```

Wikipedia has [an article about IEC 559 (or rather IEEE 754-1985)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) you might find interesting.