# Convert Double to Binary representation?

Tags: java, binary, double, type-conversion, long-integer

I tried to convert a double to its binary representation, but using this `Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d))` doesn't help, since I have large numbers, that Long can't store them i.e `2^900`.

Comment: The binary representation can only be 64-bit long as a double is 64-bit.  I don't know where 2^900 comes from.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what kind of application do you work on to need to work with such a large number ?

Comment: Useful link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397692/how-do-i-display-the-binary-representation-of-a-float-or-double

Comment: I have to do some experiments thought to do sampling on those possibilities but I see i need to do random sampling!

Answer (score 30):

`Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d))` appears to work just fine.

```
System.out.println("0:                0b" + Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(0D)));
System.out.println("1:                0b" + Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(1D)));
System.out.println("2:                0b" + Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(2D)));
System.out.println("2^900:            0b" + Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(Math.pow(2, 900))));
System.out.println("Double.MAX_VALUE: 0b" + Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(Double.MAX_VALUE)));

/*
    prints:
    0:                0b0
    1:                0b11111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    2:                0b100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    2^900:            0b111100000110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    Double.MAX_VALUE: 0b111111111101111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
*/
```

Comment: Where are the missing 63rd and 64th bits?

Answer (score 8):

You may want to process whole and fractional part :

```
public String toBinary(double d, int precision) {
    long wholePart = (long) d;
    return wholeToBinary(wholePart) + '.' + fractionalToBinary(d - wholePart, precision);
}

private String wholeToBinary(long l) {
    return Long.toBinaryString(l);
}

private String fractionalToBinary(double num, int precision) {
    StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
    while (num > 0 && binary.length() < precision) {
        double r = num * 2;
        if (r >= 1) {
            binary.append(1);
            num = r - 1;
        } else {
            binary.append(0);
            num = r;
        }
    }
    return binary.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small snippet which converts the fractional part of the double to binary format:

```java
String convertToBinary(double number) {
    int i=1;
    String num="0.";
    double temp,noofbits=32;
    while (i<=noofbits && number>0) {
        number=number*2;
        temp=Math.floor(number);
        num+=(int)temp;
        number=number-temp;
        i++;
    }
```

where noofbits gives the bitsize you want the fractional part to be limited to.
For the whole number part directly use the Integer.toBinaryString() along with the floor value of the double and append to the fractional binary string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `java.math.BigInteger` and calling `toString(int radix)` with a parameter of 2?

Comment: Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d) is only ever going to return a 64-bit `long`.

Comment: By the way, the above applies to integer numbers only -- which I have assumed to be the case based on the 2^900 you mentioned?

Comment: The thing is that i compute that using the Math.pow(2, 900) which returns double!

Comment: Yup agree :) Thanks for the help all!

Comment: @Peter : LOL ! I do repeat, "all double are 64-bit, all double are 64-bit" ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [BigInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to hold your large number and the [BigInteger.toString()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29) method to retrieve a binary representation of it.

```
BigInteger bigNum = new BigInteger(sYourNum);
System.out.println( bigNum.toString(2) );
```

Comment: this does not convert the fractional part of a **double**

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is old, and good answers are present.

I just come up with an idea that you can write the double value to a file/memory region through `DataOutputStream` and read it as bytes.

Therefore we can use ByteArrayOutputStream to hold the binary representation and fetch the bytes directly to avoid I/O operations on disk. ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeDouble(double)), [also this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436688/memory-stream-in-java))

The scala version of it looks like:

```scala
import java.io._

val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(8)
val dos = new DataOutputStream(baos)
dos.writeDouble(1.23)
dos.close()

// this 'Array[Byte]' or 'byte[]' in java holds the correct binary representation (big-endian) of the double. 
val binaryRepresentation = baos.toByteArray() 
baos.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

What I use:

```
private static final String ZEROS = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";

public String double2string(Double d) {
    String binary = Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d));
    return ZEROS.substring(binary.length()) + binary;
}

/*
0.0 => 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1.0 => 0011111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2.0 => 0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
3.0 => 0100000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
4.0 => 0100000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
5.0 => 0100000000010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
*/
```

A good place to understand these values is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format, and they are useful for

- understanding floating point representation
- writing unit tests that check doubles with total precision

Reminder: integers between -(2<sup>53</sup>-1) and 2<sup>53</sup>-1 have an exact representation as doubles.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Double.toHexString(d) and then transform the hexadecimal string into a binary one using a for loop and a StringBuilder.

Comment: Thanks this might help on my problem!