# How do I convert a Scala Double into a binary 64-bit String

Tags: scala

Basically I have a Double defined in Scala and I'd like it in a binary representation. For example:

```
val myDouble: Double = 0
val myDoubleAs64BitString = "00000000"+
                            "00000000"+
                            "00000000"+
                            "00000000"+
                            "00000000"+
                            "00000000"+
                            "00000000"+
                            "00000000"
```

This may sound and look crazy but basically for what I'm doing it's not. I'm basically writing a Chess application and I need a decent way of getting feedback while testing bitboard representations.

Comment: For everyone that read this,

http://scala-exercises.47deg.com/index.html

Comment: For a pure Java solution, you can check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359847/convert-double-to-binary-representation). Also, it's worth noting that `myDouble` is an `Int` in this example.

Comment: Thanks @resueman corrected. I'm a Java developer transitioning to Scala so unfamiliar with all the syntax just yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax in Scala is the same for this problem.

```
java.lang.Long.toBinaryString(java.lang.Double.doubleToRawLongBits(myDouble))
```