# How to get a floating-point number from its binary representation in Java?

Tags: java, binary, floating-point

I want to create a binary represenation of a floating-point number and be able to parse that number back when needed. By "binary representation" I do not mean "`0.00101`" but something like "`101000101`", that is to say, a sequesnce of `0`'s and `1`'s with no decimal separator. I need a way to both create such representation in `String` for a `double` and to parse a `double` of a `String`.
Please do not mention the X Y problem because I do definitly need this method (something like "unsigned binary value").

Thank you in advance.

[Convert Double to Binary representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359847/convert-double-to-binary-representation) seemed to solve the problem with parsing `double` to `String` but I still need help with doing the opposite: from binary to `double`.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: Of course I can create my own way of storing double's but I need the canonical one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert the bits of a `double` to a `String`, you can use [`Double.doubleToLongBits`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits-double-), which creates a `long` with the same bits as the `double`, followed by [`Long.toBinaryString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toBinaryString-long-) to convert it to a `String` with the bits as characters.

```
double test = 0.5;
long doubleBits = Double.doubleToLongBits(test);
String doubleBitsStr = Long.toBinaryString(doubleBits);
System.out.println(doubleBitsStr);
```

Output: `11111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

To convert back, use [`Long.parseLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong-java.lang.String-int-) with a radix of `2` and [`Double.longBitsToDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble-long-).

```
doubleBits = Long.parseLong(doubleBitsStr, 2);
test = Double.longBitsToDouble(doubleBits);
System.out.println(test);
```

Output: `0.5`

To convert the bits of a `float` to a `String`, you can use [`Float.floatTointBits`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits-float-), which creates an `int` with the same bits as the `float`, followed by [`Integer.toBinaryString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-) to convert it to a `String` with the bits as characters.

```
float test2 = 0.5f;
int intBits = Float.floatToIntBits(test2);
String intBitsStr = Integer.toBinaryString(intBits);
System.out.println(intBitsStr);
```

Output: `111111000000000000000000000000`

To convert back, use [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-) with a radix of `2` and [`Float.intBitsToFloat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat-int-).

```
intBits = Integer.parseInt(intBitsStr, 2);
test2 = Float.intBitsToFloat(intBits);
System.out.println(test2);
```

Output: `0.5`

Answer (score 0):

Would `Integer.toBinaryString(Float.floatToIntBits(yourNumber));` not work?