# Long.toBinaryString not returning expected binary string for 827.0

Tags: java, binary

I'm working with `double`s and need to find the binary version of `827.0`.

From looking around the way to do it is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359847/convert-double-to-binary-representation).

So I do:

```
double myDouble = 827.0;
Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(myDouble))
```

However this is returning:

`100000010001001110110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000010001001110110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000010001001110110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000010001001110110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000010001001110110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000010001001110110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000010001001110110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000010001001110110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000010001001110110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000010001001110110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000010001001110110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000010001001110110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000010001001110110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

instead of `1100111011`.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: _Start_ by writing `Long.toBinaryString((long) myDouble)`.  You're getting the guts of the floating point representation of `827.0`, for which your expectation is wrong.

Comment: Ah thank you, this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work:

```
double myDouble = 827.0;
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString((long) myDouble));
```