# How to represent double type number in binary form?

Tags: matlab, floating-point

How can I  represent double type number in binary form, for example:

```
dec = 3.14159
```

to an array consists of its IEEE 754 Double precision binary representation as [binaryconvert.com](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=051046049052049053057) does it

```
bin = 0100000000001001001000011111100111110000000110111000011001101110
```

in Matlab? I know there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397692/how-do-i-display-the-binary-representation-of-a-float-or-double), but not for Matlab.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39113-floating-point-number-conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
hexdec = num2hex(dec);
bin = hexToBinaryVector(hexdec);
```

Example:

```
hexToBinaryVector(num2hex(pi))
ans =
    1100000000001001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011000
```

Comment: FYI, [`hexToBinaryVector`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/daq/ref/hextobinaryvector.html) is in the Data Acquisition toolbox. I have most toolboxes with my academic install, but I don't think this one is common unfortunately. Also, the first bit (the sign bit?) seems to be opposite of what is returned by @LuisMendo's answer and the URL in the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `typecast(...,'uint8')` to get invididual bytes;  then `fliplr` to change byte endianness (at least that's needed on my machine); then converting each byte to binary with `dec2base(...,2,8)`; and finally `reshape`'ing to a single row:

```
bin = reshape(dec2base(fliplr(typecast(dec,'uint8')),2,8).',1,[]);
```