# Floating Point representation in Binary

Tags: c, binary, floating-point, bit, ieee

I'm trying to print the a number stored in floating point in C and I'm struggling how to print it out.
I'm doing this right now which prints the number in IEEE format. I want it printed in reverse straight from memory.
How can I fix it?
Thanks

```
void printbits(size_t n, void *c) {
    unsigned char *t = c; 
    if (c == NULL) 
        return; 
    while (n > 0) { 
        int q; 
        --n;
        for(q = 0x80; q; q >>= 1) 
            printf("%x", !!(t[n] & q));
        } 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I display the binary representation of a float or double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397692/how-do-i-display-the-binary-representation-of-a-float-or-double)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a union:

```
union u {
    float f;
    unsigned char p[4];
}
```

Then `u.f = myfloat;` and iterate on `u.p`

Comment: @MFisherKDX, note that the size of a char may vary in c, also using two members of the union is undefined behaviour in the ANSI c standard

Comment: @user3076936 Hmm ... I thought sizeof(char) was guaranteed to be 1.

Comment: @MFisherKDX you are correct, sizeof(char) is guaranteed to be 1 as sizeof returns the size of an object in chars, it does not however guarantee that a char has 8 bits

Comment: @user3076936 So we this this pattern all the time. Is this wrong?  `unsigned char c = (x >> 8)&0xff`

Comment: @MFisherKDX yes, in ANSI c it would be more correctly:
unsigned char c  = (x >> CHAR_BIT) &((char)(-1));