# Python print floating point number in binary?

Tags: python

Is there a way to print a floating point number in binary in Python? Something like

```
>>> f"{0.5:b}" 
0.1
```

? The above doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/12170503/1540468 ?